# CakePHP $this->Auth->Login() always returning false

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

Been trying to figure this out for plenty of hours, but without success.

$this->request->data['Login'] array contains the right username and hash which matches the entry in the database. $this->Auth->login(); is always returning false for some reason.

The Login table has a column called UserID and Password, Password is hashed using MD5 and a salt which is stored in the table Login as well.

I tried adding a beforeSave function in the Login model which hashed the password, but this didn't seem to work either?

/app/Controller/AppController.php

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {
    public $helpers = array('App', 'Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array(
        'Session', 
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'login', 'action' => 'authenticate'),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'account', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'),
            'authenticate' => array('Form' => array('userModel' => 'Login', 'fields' => array('username' => 'UserID', 'password' => 'Password'))))
    );

    // Execute on every page load.
    public function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
    }
}
```

/app/Controller/LoginController.php

```
<?php
class loginController extends AppController{
    public $uses = array('Login');

    public function index(){
        $this->render('/login');
    }

    public function authenticate(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->request->data['Login']['password'] = $this->hashPassword($this->data['Login']);
            if($this->Auth->login()){
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username or password.');
            return $this->redirect('/login');
        }
    }

    private function hashPassword($login){
        // Get the salt of the user.
        $salt = $this->Login->find('first', array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Salt'),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Login.UserID' => $login['username'])));
        return md5(md5($login['password']) . $salt['Login']['Salt']);
    }
}
```

/app/Model/Login.php

```
<?php
class Login extends AppModel{
    public $useTable = 'Login';

    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Please fill in all of the fields.'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Please fill in all of the fields.'
            )
        ));
}
```

/app/View/login.ctp

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Session->flash('flash', array('element' => 'fail'));
    echo $this->Form->create('Login', array('url' => '/login/authenticate'));
    echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'autocomplete' => 'off'));
    echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => false, 'div' => false));
    echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the incredibly detailed example in the CakePHP book:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

You shouldn't be manually hashing your password prior to submitting.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it doesn't answer my question. If I'm not supposed to manually hash my password, how am I supposed to do it the right way?

Comment: Remove any/every line where you're manually hashing the password, then read the tutorial on where it shows that the only place you need to hash it is in the beforeSave().

Answer (score 0):

Alright I solved it:

- Changed the field names in the login view file to match the column names in the database.
- Added a custom PasswordHasher